# JSON metedata file writing nestled floats to .txt or .csv

Tags: gis

Very new to python so please forgive me if this is a silly question but I have been attempting to loop an extraction of certain information within a .json file (specifically the date and one value in particular) in order to create a time series. Due to me having over 300 files I would like this to be done automatically, in order to easily create a time series of certain values. I have managed to print the data, however have failed to extract this information to a text file that would be readable in something like excel.

Please find attached both the example .json file I am trying to extract and my code so far. Thanks!

> {
>       "AcquasitionInfo": {
>           "Date": {
>               "Day": 27,
>               "Month": 3,
>               "Year": 2011
>           },
>           "EarthSunDistance": 0.9977766,
>           "SolarAzimuth": 154.94013617,
>           "SolarZenith": 53.1387049,
>           "Time": {
>               "Hour": 11,
>               "Minute": 0,
>               "Second": 21
>           },
>           "sensorAzimuth": 0.0,
>           "sensorZenith": 0.0
>       },
>       "FileInfo": {
>           "CLOUD_MASK": "LS5TM_20110327_lat53lon354_r23p204_clouds.kea",
>           "FileBaseName": "LS5TM_20110327_lat53lon354_r23p204",
>           "IMAGE_DEM": "LS5TM_20110327_lat53lon354_r23p204_dem.kea",
>           "METADATA": "LS5TM_20110327_lat53lon354_r23p204_meta.json",
>           "ProviderMetadata": "LT05_L1TP_204023_20110327_20161208_01_T1_MTL.txt",
>           "RADIANCE": "LS5TM_20110327_lat53lon354_r23p204_vmsk_mclds_rad.kea",
>           "RADIANCE_WHOLE": "LS5TM_20110327_lat53lon354_r23p204_vmsk_rad.kea",
>           "SREF_6S_IMG": "LS5TM_20110327_lat53lon354_r23p204_vmsk_mclds_topshad_rad_srefdem.kea",
>           "STD_SREF_IMG": "LS5TM_20110327_lat53lon354_r23p204_vmsk_mclds_topshad_rad_srefdem_stdsref.kea",
>           "THERMAL_BRIGHT": "LS5TM_20110327_lat53lon354_r23p204_vmsk_thrad_thermbright.kea",
>           "THERMAL_BRIGHT_WHOLE": "LS5TM_20110327_lat53lon354_r23p204_vmsk_thrad_thermbright.kea",
>           "THERM_RADIANCE_WHOLE": "LS5TM_20110327_lat53lon354_r23p204_vmsk_thermrad.kea",
>           "TOA": "LS5TM_20110327_lat53lon354_r23p204_vmsk_mclds_rad_toa.kea",
>           "TOA_WHOLE": "LS5TM_20110327_lat53lon354_r23p204_vmsk_rad_toa.kea",
>           "TOPO_SHADOW_MASK": "LS5TM_20110327_lat53lon354_r23p204_toposhad.kea",
>           "VALID_MASK": "LS5TM_20110327_lat53lon354_r23p204_valid.kea",
>           "VIEW_ANGLE": "LS5TM_20110327_lat53lon354_r23p204_viewangle.kea"
>       },
>       "ImageInfo": {
>           "CellSizeRefl": 30.0,
>           "CellSizeTherm": 30.0,
>           "CloudCover": 52.0,
>           "CloudCoverLand": 79.0
>       },
>       "LocationInfo": {
>           "Geographical": {
>               "BBOX": {
>                   "BLLat": 52.06993,
>                   "BLLon": -5.34028,
>                   "BRLat": 52.08621,
>                   "BRLon": -1.72003,
>                   "TLLat": 54.09075,
>                   "TLLon": -5.45257,
>                   "TRLat": 54.10827,
>                   "TRLon": -1.65856
>               },
>               "CentreLat": 53.10330325240661,
>               "CentreLon": -3.5429440927905724
>           },
>           "Projected": {
>               "BBOX": {
>                   "BLX": 354735.0,
>                   "BLY": 5776815.0,
>                   "BRX": 572985.0,
>                   "BRY": 5776815.0,
>                   "TLX": 354735.0,
>                   "TLY": 5992035.0,
>                   "TRX": 572985.0,
>                   "TRY": 5992035.0
>               },
>               "CentreX": 463860.0,
>               "CentreY": 5884425.0,
>               "VPOLY": {
>                   "MaxXX": 572985.0,
>                   "MaxXY": 5950185.0,
>                   "MaxYX": 405795.0,
>                   "MaxYY": 5992035.0,
>                   "MinXX": 354735.0,
>                   "MinXY": 5819025.0,
>                   "MinYX": 521775.0,
>                   "MinYY": 5776815.0
>               }
>           }
>       },
>       "ProductsInfo": {
>           "ARCSIProducts": [
>               "CLOUDS",
>               "DOSAOTSGL",
>               "STDSREF",
>               "METADATA"
>           ],
>           "ARCSI_AOT_RANGE_MAX": 0.5,
>           "ARCSI_AOT_RANGE_MIN": 0.05,
>           "ARCSI_AOT_VALUE": 0.5,
>           "ARCSI_CLOUD_COVER": 0.627807080745697,
>           "ARCSI_LUT_ELEVATION_MAX": 1100,
>           "ARCSI_LUT_ELEVATION_MIN": -100,
>           "ProcessDate": {
>               "Day": 11,
>               "Month": 7,
>               "Year": 2018
>           },
>           "ProcessTime": {
>               "Hour": 7,
>               "Minute": 24,
>               "Second": 55
>           }
>       },
>       "SensorInfo": {
>           "ARCSISensorName": "LS5TM",
>           "Path": 204,
>           "Row": 23,
>           "SensorID": "TM",
>           "SpacecraftID": "LANDSAT_5"
>       },
>       "SoftwareInfo": {
>           "Name": "ARCSI",
>           "URL": "http://www.rsgislib.org/arcsi",
>           "Version": "3.1.4"
>       } }

```
import glob
import json
jsonfile = glob.glob('*.json')
with open(jsonfile[0]) as f:
        data = json.load(f)
print(data["AcquasitionInfo"]["Date"]["Day"])
print(data["AcquasitionInfo"]["Date"]["Month"])
print(data["AcquasitionInfo"]["Date"]["Year"])
print(data["ProductsInfo"]["ARCSI_AOT_VALUE"])
with open('data.txt', 'w') as outfile:
    json.dump(["ProductsInfo"]["ARCSI_AOT_VALUE"], outfile)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You forgot the `data` in the last line :

```
import glob
import json
jsonfile = glob.glob('*.json')
with open(jsonfile[0]) as f:
        data = json.load(f)
print(data["AcquasitionInfo"]["Date"]["Day"])
print(data["AcquasitionInfo"]["Date"]["Month"])
print(data["AcquasitionInfo"]["Date"]["Year"])
print(data["ProductsInfo"]["ARCSI_AOT_VALUE"])
with open('data.txt', 'w') as outfile:
     json.dump(data["ProductsInfo"]["ARCSI_AOT_VALUE"], outfile)
```

**EDIT:**

You can do like this :

```
import json
import os

for file in os.listdir("."):
    if file.endswith(".json"):
        with open(file) as f:
            data = json.load(f)
            with open('data.txt', 'a') as outfile:
                json.dump(data["ProductsInfo"]["ARCSI_AOT_VALUE"], outfile)
                outfile.write(';')
```

Comment: Thank you that's one problem down. I'm now trying to make all .json files in a directory run this process in a 'for' loop, adding each files specific information to the same output text file. Any help would be appreciated!